# Can't get Pattern.matches(regExExpression) to work?

Tags: java, regex

I have a directory with thousands of files that follow a finite number of different naming conventions. I am trying to use RegEx to help me identify the file naming conventions as I iterate over the files name list. I will then use this logic to choose the correct file name parsing methodology.

This is my code:

```
//Define regex rule <br>
String regExRule = "Final_[0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{1,4}([.][0-9]{1,3})_[A-Za-z0-9]+([.][0-9]{1,3})?[.]wav";

//Compile the rule <br>
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regExRule);

//See if there is a match <br>
Matcher m = p.matcher("Final_0-1.1_FirstLast.4.wav");

//See if there is a match <br>
if(m.matches()){ //we have a match}



//   Always returns false even though I can confirm the rule works using
//this tool: https://www.regextester.com/

    Rule: <br>
    Final_[0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{1,4}([.][0-9]{1,3})_[A-Za-z0-9]+([.][0-9]{1,3})?[.]wav
```

Test String:

```
Final_0-1.1_FirstLast.4.wav
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the wrong behavior -- your example code produces a match (true) on all JDKs I tried (1.8 to 12)...

Answer (score -1):

Your original expression appears to be working well, if I understand the problem right, we would just then replace `[.]` with `\.`, if you wish:

```
Final_[0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{1,4}(\.[0-9]{1,3})_[A-Za-z0-9]+([.][0-9]{1,3})?\.wav
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gUycGi/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "Final_[0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{1,4}(\\.[0-9]{1,3})_[A-Za-z0-9]+([.][0-9]{1,3})?\\.wav";
final String string = "Final_0-1.1_FirstLast.4.wav";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Emma, Thank you very much for looking into this for me. I was able to use your code example with success! Not sure why my code didn't work... Thanks again!